# How do I group rows based on a fixed sum of values in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find another solution to below Excel formula that was already provided here:

[How do I create groups based on the sum of values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38272408/how-do-i-create-groups-based-on-the-sum-of-values)

It is the same requirement, but the grouping criteria needs to be an exact value.

Here's the sample data:

```
Column A | Column B
Item A | 1
Item B | 2
Item C | 3
Item D | 4
Item E | 5
Item F | 1
Item G | 2
Item H | 3
Item I | 4
Item J | 5
```

I need to group the rows if their Column B sum = 5.

Expected result:

```
Group 1 = Item A, Item D (1 + 4) = 5
Group 2 = Item B, Item C (2 + 3) = 5
Group 3 = Item E = 5
Group 4 = Item F, Item I (1 + 4) = 5
Group 5 = Item G, Item H (2 + 3) = 5
Group 6 = Item J = 5
```

If a row's Column B exceeds 5 or does not have another matching row to equal 5 when added then it will have no Group value.

Groupings can be interchangeable, ie. Group 1 = Item A, Item I can be made since 1 + 4 = 5.

I assume this can be achieved using Excel formulas but I am struggling to find which formula(s) can be used.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Would you provide an excel sample (screenshot) on how you would like to visualize such grouping? From your expected result it is clear how you want to group the information, but this grouping can be visualized in very different ways.

Comment: @DavidLeal thanks for looking at my question.  Here's an Excel sample:

Comment: ![Valid XHTML](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13ZcvcXsLmLqgn1t74_Kewng9TtF7gpI6/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @DavidLeal sorry I am new to the site and I could not figure out how to attach an image. Hopefully you can view the link I sent above.  My data are columns ITEM and # OF PIECES.  The TOTAL, STARTS GROUP, and GROUP # are formulas I used using the previous page I mentioned above.  I highlighted those groups #5 and #8 since they are less than 5.  I need the groups to total exactly 5, and anything over or less will not have a group.  ITEM_N can be added to ITEM_K to make group 5 valid.  Then only ITEM_O and ITEM_P will not have a group since their sum is < 5.

Comment: I provided  @Enjay a possible solution, assuming your are looking for only consecutive numbers for grouping, in your question you state A and D form a group, but in the screenshot you don't take into account this case, so I assume this is typo and the rule only applies for consecutive numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I was able to understand your question after some comments exchanged. Anyway I would recommend to *update your question, it is an interesting problem, but the question was difficult to follow*.

Before looking for an Excel solution, I took the approach of understanding the problem as a state machine with the transition from one state to another. I considered the following states that represent the position the item in the group. A group is defined as consecutive items that the sum of all items is equal to `5`.

1. `EMPTY`: Just the initial situation
2. `START`: Start of the group
3. `MIDDLE`: A middle element of the group
4. `END`: The end of the group
5. `START-END`: A group with a single element
6. `NA`: Not applicable group

I follow the same idea of: [How do I create groups based on the sum of values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38272408/how-do-i-create-groups-based-on-the-sum-of-values), but slightly different helper columns:

1. **Total** (Column `D`), but for this case it is used the following formula: `IF(SUM(C3,D2)>5,C3,SUM(C3,D2))`
2. **Status** or item position within Group (Column `G`). Here is where it is calculated the corresponding status for each element
3. **Checks for Valid Groups** (Column `H`): Evaluates if a group is valid. When there is no match to `5`, the group is not valid. It is indicated at the row that represents the beginning of the group (`START` or `START-END` states). If `TRUE` it means a valid group, if `FALSE` it is not a valid group, and `NA` for an `NA` value from **Status** column. If empty represents any element of the group that is not the first one.
4. **Group #** (Column `I`): To identify the group the row (Item) belongs to. Notice that we start counting the group from `1` and I also consider the case a group can not be formed (`NA`).

Here is a screenshot with the solution and the formula on `G3`:

```
=LET(total, D3, prevS, G2, QTY, C3,
    IF(C3="", "",
        IF(OR(AND(total=5, QTY<5, prevS="START"), AND(total=5, prevS="MIDDLE")), "END",
            IF(OR(AND(total>5, total=QTY, OR(prevS="START", prevS="MIDDLE")),AND(total>5, OR(prevS="", prevS="END", prevS="NA", prevS="START-END"))), "NA",
                IF(OR(AND(total<5, total=QTY, OR(prevS="START", prevS="MIDDLE")),AND(total<5, OR(prevS="", prevS="END", prevS="NA", prevS="START-END"))), "START", 
                    IF(AND(total<5, OR(prevS="START", prevS="MIDDLE")), "MIDDLE",
                        IF(OR(AND(total=5, total= QTY, OR(prevS="START", prevS="MIDDLE")),AND(total=5, OR(prevS="", prevS="END", prevS="NA", prevS="START-END"))), "START-END", "UNDEFINED")
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

**Notes:**:

1. `LET` Excel function is used to have something more readable
2. The `IF` blocks should to be ordered from the most specific case of `total` and `QTY` values to the most generic ones. For the case with same `total` condition, make sure the second condition for `prevS` are not repeated.
3. Added as a last resort `UNDEFINED` case, to check if any transition was not covered, if that is the case it has to be reviewed, so far in the sample data all cases are covered

[image: sample excel file]

Column `K-Q` is just for documenting purpose to identify all possible transitions. Column `K-M` provides all possible transitions organized them by previous status. The columns `O`-`Q` represent all possible transitions ordered by current status, so it is easier to formulate each portion of the `IF` blocks.

Maybe the formula can be simplified, compared to the solution provided by the similar question is more complex, but this question has more specific conditions. Some transitions maybe not relevant for the final result, but it is preferred to consider all positions in the group to make sure all transitions are covered.

The following state machine diagram shows all possible transitions:

[image: state machine diagram]

**Notes:**

As you can see the solution also considers when a group cannot be created or non valid groups (`NA` values). The solution considers that **Item** column has only positive values, it is not stated in the question any restriction, but looking at the example they are all positives. To consider zero values, this solution needs to be adjusted.

**Checks for Valid Groups** column is calculated as follow:

```
= IF(G3="", "", 
    IF(G3="START-END", TRUE,
        IF(G3="NA", "NA",
            IF(G3="START",
                LET(endRow, IFNA(MATCH("START", LEFT(G4:$G$1000,5),0), MATCH("", LEFT(G4:$G$1000,5),0))+ ROW()-1, 
                    value, VLOOKUP("END", G4:INDIRECT( "G" & endRow),1,0), 
                    IF(ISNA(value), FALSE, TRUE)
                ), ""
            )
        )
    )
)
```

It identifies the start and end of the group, and then finds any `NA` values, if there are, then it is not a valid group. If the end of the candidate group is not found (the first `MATCH` returns `N/A`), then is searches until a blank row

**Group #** column is calculated has follow:

```
=IF(C3="","", LET(value, MAX($I$2:I2), IF(G3="NA", "NA", 
  IF(H3=TRUE, value + 1, IF(H3=FALSE, "NA", 
  IF(I2="NA", "NA", value))))))
```

This way only valid transaction are considered, i.e. the following status transitions starting from `START` but not ending in `END` : `START->NA`, `START->MIDDLE[one or more]...->NA` and `NA` are **not** considered valid groups (`NA`).

I added more examples from the original sample file provided, more can be added to further test all possible scenarios, but *I guess you get the idea about this approach*. As you sated "I assume this can be achieved using Excel formulas" yes it is possible, but I would say for more complex conditions I would suggest to implement a state machine algorithm in VBA. Even it is possible to do it with Excel functions, you have to deal with several nested `IF` blocks and helper columns, something that can be achieved with a simple for-loop in VBA.

Here is a link to [online Excel file](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlZxw2GG3C7Ihze7yZxLAaO2QVpJ?e=CUrzq8) I used.

Comment: Hello @DavidLeal.  Thank you for this detailed analysis and instructions.  I really appreciate it.  I tried it on another sample data set and it does not seem to work on adjacent rows that result to a total > 5.   https://drive.google.com/file/d/15ZUxT1aDzouq8ORvnM97meYayTope2Ca/view?usp=sharing

ITEMS J thru Q were unable to form a new group.  J+L should be a new group, and K+M can also be a new group.  It is complicated to use Excel functions that work on various data sets.  I will just try your other suggestion to use VBA.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Enjay, I updated the answer, I forgot to include the transition: `NA->START`.  That is why I added `UNDEFINED` status, to identify any transition not included based on additional sample testing values. About additional cases, please refer to my original excel file so I can follow you and add there any additional case so I can review it. Also please update your question with your specific business rules and  expected results (or better create a new question if they are significantly different). The rows you are referring I don't know if they belong to my excel file or your screenshot.

Comment: @Enjay I updated the solution to consider some scenarios don't form a group. i added also an additional tab: `AddionalTests` to consider such scenarios. Please review it and let me know. If you consider it works as expected, please accept the answer. Thanks

Comment: Hello @DavidLeal, thank you very much again for the updates.  I really appreciate it.  It partially solves my problem.  There are still NA group #'s in your Excel sample that can total 5 (ITEM K + U, ITEM V + AC).  I will just copy & paste those NA rows to a new worksheet and re-run the same formulas until all NA groupings have been exhausted.

Comment: Hello @Enjoy,  in the example you are indicating in jour previous  comment are not consecutive. In the previous question you referred are consecutive values. That would require to run a second pass to identify from ungrouped items if the can form a group with other ungrouped values that are not consecutive. This way is a combinatorial problem to find all subsets can be created from Qty that sum 5 i.e. `{5}`, `{4,1}`, `{3,2}`, `{1,2,2}`, `{1,1,1,2}`, `{1,1,1,1,1}` regardless of the order, but that would be a different problem and I don’t think excel would help, better VBA

Comment: yes agree. Excel formulas may not handle it. Thanks again for your help.